# Error when trying to carry out Exception Handling

Tags: python, pandas, exception

I am trying to handle a HTTP IncompleteRead Error, through the code below. However, I find that whenever I call `message` to see if the Exception Handling works I get the Error `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` in the line `df = update(currency)[1]` despite trying to handle for the case when `update` returns a `NoneType`.

```
import csv
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pprint import pprint, pformat
import http.client
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def update(ABBRV):
    if ABBRV == 'LAB':
        try:

                my_url = 'http://www.bankofcanada.ca/stats/results/csv'
                data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"lookupPage": "lookup_yield_curve.php",
                                     "startRange": "1986-01-01",
                                     "searchRange": "all"})

                binary_data = data.encode('utf-8')
                req = urllib.request.Request(my_url, binary_data)
                result = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                zipdata = result.read()

                #In case of http.client.IncompleteRead Error
        except http.client.IncompleteRead as e:
            df = update(ABBRV)[1]
            return df

            zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(zipdata))  
            df = pd.read_csv(zipfile.open(zipfile.namelist()[0]))                    
            df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Date'])

            def getYear(s):
                x = re.search('(\d+)',s)
                return (float(x.groups()[0]))/100 if x is not None else 'empty string'

            if df is None:
                dict = {}
                symbols = ['Date','Mat', 'VAL', 'ABBRV']
                for l in symbols:
                    dict0[l] = 0
                    df = pd.Series(dict0, name='Data')

            return [df, result]

    if ABBRV != 'LAB':
        raise ValueError

def message(ABBRV):
    df = update(ABBRV)[1]
    if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame) != 1:
        return 300
    else:
        return 200
```

Calling the function:

```
sg = message('LAB')
print sg
```

Thank You

**Edit**: Is this portion of code doing nothing to prevent the return of a `None` type? Also, Edited indentation issues with the code above to reflect Anand S Kumar's suggestions.

```
if df is None:
    dict = {}
    symbols = ['Date','Mat', 'VAL', 'ABBRV']
    for l in symbols:
        dict0[l] = 0
        df = pd.Series(dict0, name='Data')
```

Comment: You're not handling the case when it returns a nonetype. Surround `df = update(ABBRV)[1]` with a try except to handle that case.

Comment: @Brobin The error arises in the `message()` function. Do you mean I need a try-except there to handle this?

Comment: Yes. Or you could check if the return value of update is not `None`.

Comment: @Brobin Do you think this makes sense `except Exception as e:
                try:
                    df = self.update(currency)[1]
                except Exception as f:
                    if f is None:
                        df = self.update(currency)[1]
                    return df`?

Answer (score 1):

I see few issues in the code -

1. Inside the try function, if no error occurs you are not returning anything, if you do not return anything from a function, then it would be like the function is returning `None` , hence assuming there is no error in the `url` getting side, you will end up returning `None` and then trying to call `[1]` for a `NoneType` , causing the issue in your question.
2. If an IncompleteRead Exception has occured , you are again calling `update(currency)` what makes you think if the first time read was unsuccessful , the second time it would be successful? To me it looks like if there is an IncompleteRead Exception , the function would go into infinite recursion and end with the following error after sometime - `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` .
3. The condition `if ABBRV != 'LAB': raise ValueError` is inside the condition - `if ABBRV == 'LAB':` , the first condition I said (not equals) would never be true, I think you wanted to put that condition outside the if block (would be good to put an `else` , rather than checking another condition again).
4. A recommendation is that instead of calling the function as - `df = update(ABBRV)[1]` maybe you can split them into two lines, get the result of `update(ABBRV)` first, then check if its `None`, if it isn't `None` , then call `[1]` on it and do the rest of the logic.

Comment: Thank You. I am working under the assumption that if I call `update(ABBRV)[1]` enough times I will get the data I want. So, do you think this change makes sense: `except http.client.IncompleteRead as e:
                    df = self.update(currency)
                    while df is None:
                        df = self.update(currency)
                    if df is not None:
                        df = self.update(currency)[1]
                        return df`

Comment: do not do this inside the `update()` function, do it outside, function calls are expensive and recursions do not work that way, it will never reach the while loop, because in second time call to update() again first it will call update() just after the `except` statement and this will keep on happenning

Comment: I know that you say I should do it outside `update()`, but I'm calling it in multiple places so I worry that won't be easy to do. Do you think this makes sense `except Exception as e:
                try:
                    df = self.update(currency)[1]
                except Exception as f:
                    if f is None:
                        df = self.update(currency)[1]
                    return df`

Comment: If you cannot do outside `update()` then do a while loop inside the `update()` function (not infinite while loop, maybe untill a number of times) , recursion is not suited for this. While loop would have conditions like `i=0 while i<100 and ABBRV == 'LAB': i += 1`